# How to disable a tab until form elements are complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my example below, I've managed to disable the next button until the form field (Case Title) has content in it. I don't quite understand how to disable the next tab until that form field is complete.

**How can I disable the other tabs until the form field in the first tab is completed?**

```js
$(".btnNext").click(function () {
  $(".nav-tabs > .active").next("li").find("a").trigger("click");
});

$(".btnPrevious").click(function () {
  $(".nav-tabs > .active").prev("li").find("a").trigger("click");
});

let caseTitle = document.getElementById("caseTitle");
let caseTitleNext = document.querySelector("#tab1 .btnNext");

caseTitle.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  caseTitleNext.removeAttribute("disabled");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="ibox-content">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Case Creation <i class="fa-solid fa-folder"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Attributes <i class="fa-duotone fa-circle-nodes"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Individual Involvement <i class="fa-solid fa-person"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">Agency Involvement <i class="fa-solid fa-building"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab">Review Information <i class="fa-solid fa-memo"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form id="createCase" name="createCase">
    <div class="panel blank-panel">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="caseTitle" class="is-required">Case Title</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="caseTitle">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Case Number</label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter case number" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btnPrevious">Cancel</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext" disabled="disabled">Next</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <h2>Tab 2 Content</h2>
            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btnNext">Skip</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
            <h2>Tab 3 Content</h2>
            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
            <h2>Tab 4 Content</h2>
            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
            <h2>Tab 5 Content</h2>
            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: add a required attrib to the input, then use css, something like `body:has(#tab1 .form-control:invalid) a[data-toggle="tab"] {  pointer-events: none; opacity: 0.5; }`, but maybe a bit more robust. keypoint :`:has()`

Comment: I am looking for a JavaScript/jQuery solution to this.

Comment: @Millhorn Why do you want a more complicated solution if you can just use this?

Comment: It's just the set up that I have. My CSS isn't global, but my javascript is. It's just the way I have my site set up...

Comment: fun fact: you can add css with javascript. `$("head").append("<style>"+css+"</style>");`

Comment: @dandavis I tried your CSS solution, but it ends up lightening the tab background and removing functionality on all the tabs. That wasn't my goal. As the original post states, I need to recognize when the "Case Title" field has content, and then allow the other tabs to be clicked on, the same way the next button works on that first tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on the Bootstrap docs, you can [disable tabs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#nav-disabled-links) by setting `<li class="disabled">` and removing the `tab` from `data-toggle`. I wrote a `setTabDisabled(tabElement)` method for quick toggling

Here is a working example

```js
$(".btnNext").click(function () {
  $(".nav-tabs > .active").next("li").find("a").trigger("click");
});

$(".btnPrevious").click(function () {
  $(".nav-tabs > .active").prev("li").find("a").trigger("click");
});

let caseTitle = document.getElementById("caseTitle");
let caseTitleNext = document.querySelector("#tab1 .btnNext");


const setTabDisabled = (tabEl, isDisabled = true) => {
  tabEl.setAttribute("class", isDisabled ? "disabled" : "");
  const tabLink = tabEl.querySelector('a');
  tabLink.setAttribute("data-toggle", isDisabled ? "" : "tab");  
};

const setNonActiveTabsDisabled = (isDisabled = true) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.nav.nav-tabs li:not(.active)').forEach(element => {
    setTabDisabled(element, isDisabled);
    });
};

caseTitle.addEventListener("keyup", () => {
  if(caseTitle.value.trim().length){
    caseTitleNext.removeAttribute("disabled");
    setNonActiveTabsDisabled(false);
  }
  else{
    caseTitleNext.setAttribute("disabled","");
    setNonActiveTabsDisabled(true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="ibox-content">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Case Creation <i class="fa-solid fa-folder"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled">
      <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="">Attributes <i class="fa-duotone fa-circle-nodes"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled">
      <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="">Individual Involvement <i class="fa-solid fa-person"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled">
      <a href="#tab4" data-toggle="">Agency Involvement <i class="fa-solid fa-building"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li class="disabled">
      <a href="#tab5" data-toggle="">Review Information <i class="fa-solid fa-memo"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form id="createCase" name="createCase">
    <div class="panel blank-panel">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="caseTitle" class="is-required">Case Title</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="caseTitle">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Case Number</label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter case number" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btnPrevious">Cancel</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext" disabled="disabled">Next</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <h2>Tab 2 Content</h2>
            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btnNext">Skip</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
            <h2>Tab 3 Content</h2>
            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
            <h2>Tab 4 Content</h2>
            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnNext">Next</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
            <h2>Tab 5 Content</h2>
            <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btnPrevious">Previous</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```